# Percentage of Values for a Symmetrical Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

For a Normal distribution, we can say that the percentage of values under a certain z-score is the same as the probability till that z-score. For instance, for a z-score of 0.30 the probability till 0.30 is 0.1179+0.5000=0.6179. This is the same as the percentage of values under 0.30 which is 61.79 %.

For non-symmetrical distribution, my understanding is that the above does not hold true.

However, does the above hold for other symmetrical distributions (say arcsine, etc)? If it does not hold for other symmetrical distributions, can we have a similar proposition for these distributions?

Adding an example from the Standard Normal distribution for more clarity.

We have that P(z<-1)=.1587. This result we can also use to say that the number of values from -inf to -1 is 15.87 % of the total values from -inf to +inf.

So, what I am thinking is does this hold only for normal distribution or can we generalize this statement with the probability distribution for any symmetrical distribution. If it does not hold for other symmetrical distribution, can we make a similar proposition involving the probability distribution in some way or the other for these other symmetrical distributions?

For non-symmetrical distributions, my understanding is that such a proposition is not possible.

Comment: I do not think symmetry is the issue here. Can you edit your post to let us have more details about what you understand and what is puzzling you?

Comment: I know what you're asking, but we shouldn't talk about the z-score. z-score would only sense only for certain distributions.

Comment: I'm tempted to say YES. But I'm curious about existence of means. Moreover, I'm not sure how to prove it.